# infinite error message python

Tags: python, cmd, warnings, indefinite

I am in deep trouble at the moment. After every letter I type on my python 
command prompt in Linux, I get an error message:

sys:1: GtkWarning: Attempting to store changes into `/u/rnayar/.recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/u/rnayar/.recently-used.xbel.L6ETZW': Too many open files

Hence I can type nothing on python, and the prompt is stuck.

I tried to open 185 fits files, containing some data, and feed in some of that data into an
array. I cannot abandon the command window, because I already have significant amounts of information stored on it.
Does anybody know how I can stop the error message and get it working as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening and storing information from one file at a time?  We dont have enough information to understand what is wrong with your code.  We really dont have much more than "I tried to open 185 fits files"  and "too many open files"